# How to merge two scripts and trigger them both at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, merge

I am writing an website from the scratch probably for the first time and I am stucked in javascript.
My idea is to trigger the link by a click which will run two javascripts at once.
Here is the situation:

Link to click:

```
<li><p class="button"><a href="video_iframe.html" target="iframe">VIDEO</a></p></li>
```

Iframe as a target:

```
<li><iframe width="800px" height="1000px" frameBorder="0" name="iframe"></iframe></li>
```

js 1:

```
<script>
$('.button').click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('active');
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('#zelena').stop().animate({
        left: 151
    });
} else {
    $('#zelena').stop().animate({
        left: -649
    });
}
});
</script>
```

js 2:

```
<script>
$(".button").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("underline");
$(".button").not(this).removeClass("underline");

}); 
</script>
```

here I uploaded the whole website: http://www.filedropper.com/mgwebslidefinaliframe

(The problem is that I have to click 2 times at "VIDEO" link/button to show the iframe content and that´s the problem, because on the second click It should close like It´s doing right now. So we can´t see the iframe content because of the no needed second click...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: set up a q, or a defer/promise, or just plain call the next function at the bottom of the first.

Comment: You basically want to trigger two functions on a single click right??

Comment: Yes, I just dont know how to merge the two functions to perform on a single click, I really dont understand js yet...

Comment: I don't quite fully understand what you're trying to do in the second function but it looks like just toggle the underline class? if you could explain what that script is for maybe i can help you

Comment: why not 

$('.button').click(function () {
//js1
$(this).toggleClass('active');
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('#zelena').stop().animate({
        left: 151
    });
} else {
    $('#zelena').stop().animate({
        left: -649
    });
}
// js2
$(this).toggleClass("underline");
$(".button").not(this).removeClass("underline");

});

Comment: why cant you simply trigger the second function at the end of the first?

Comment: Maybe the second function is not causing the problem, I dont know... It´s just my gues. When you download the files I sent and open the mg_web.html, then click to "VIDEO" link/button on the left side and then you can see the error, the iframe I am calling didnt show up, it shows only on the second click on the "VIDEO" link/button when the iframe window is already closing/sliding away... I need to slide  the iframe window to the right plus show the content of it´s html (lorem ipsum). So I really dont know what is causing the issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active underline');
    $(".button.underline").not(this).removeClass("underline");
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('#zelena').stop().animate({
            left: 151
        });
    } else {
        $('#zelena').stop().animate({
            left: -649
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry I tried this and I have the same problem, so I am sorry I wrongly estimated what caused the problem. Problem is somewhere else I dont know where... I tried to describe it above...

Answer (score 0):

You have added the reference to the button. Just add the following attribute to your iframe tag: src="video_iframe.html" and remove the a tag added to the button. I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, this is working, thank you :) but can I after that change the scource of the html? I mean I´d like to have multiple src="....._iframe.html" on one iframe, Is it possible?

Comment: You can surely do it.

Comment: Just change the src attribute of the iframe on individual button click.

Comment: Can it be done automatickly by clicking the individual button from menu? (When I click video, iframe will show video.html, when I click login, iframe will show login.html etc?)

Comment: Yup. Do $('[name="iframe"]').src = "_pagelink" in the button on click function. You will just have to figure out a way to pass some parameter to figure out which button was clicked. Or write a separate on click function of each button.

Comment: So, I made this: `<li><p id="video" class="button"><a target="iframe">VIDEO</a></p></li>` `<li><p id="kontakt" class="button"><a target="iframe">KONTAKT</a></p></li>` `<script>
$("#video").on("click", function() {
 $('[name="iframe"]').src = "video_iframe.html"
}); 
</script>

<script>
$("#kontakt").on("click", function() {
 $('[name="iframe"]').src = "kontakt_iframe.html"
}); 
</script>` but I don´t know what I should put into the iframe line: `<li><iframe width="800px" height="1000px" frameBorder="0" name="iframe" src=""></iframe></li>` What should I put to "src" of the code to make it work?

Comment: With the code you have posted, what is happening when you click on video or kontakt?

Comment: Nothing is happening, the iframe window inside the webpage is blank, just empty, and content of called htmls is not showing, the iframe content is not loaded, but the iframe window is there.